# How to access children of an object using a string variable?

Tags: php

I have a function where I want to work with an object. I would like to specify a child of that object with a string. I know the child is possible with `$x`, but is it possible to go deeper with something like `$y`, too?

```
<?php
    $obj = new stdClass;
    $obj->token = new stdClass;
    $obj->token->id = 123;

    $x = 'created'; 
    $obj->token->{$x} = 456;    

    $y = 'token->updated';
    $obj->{$y} = 789;   

    print_r($obj);
?>
```

Obviously, that doesn't work, but I would like to get

```
stdClass Object
(
    [token] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 123
            [created] => 456
            [updated] => 789
        )

)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use `$obj->token->updated = 789;`

Comment: surely that would work, but the requirement is that the destination of the data come from a config file as a text.

Answer (score 2):

It would not work if you include the arrow.
This on the other hand works:

```
$obj->{$x}->{$y} = 111;
```

If the arrow is something you have to have in the variable you can do some trickery like this:

```
$deepVar = 'token->update';
$a = &$obj;
foreach (explode('->', $deepVar) as $varName) {
    $a = &$a->{$varName};
}
$a = 111;
unset($a);
```